# typescript 1.5 beta in webstorm 10.0.2, get an error: TS2304-Cannot find name 'DataView'

Tags: typescript, webstorm

The newest typescript 1.5 beta, Webstorm 10.0.2, for the code snippet:

```
let a: typeof DataView;
let b: typeof Map;
let c: typeof WeakMap;
let d: typeof Set;
```

I get four errors:

```
Error:(1, 15) TS2304: Cannot find name 'DataView'.
Error:(4, 15) TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
Error:(3, 15) TS2304: Cannot find name 'WeakMap'.
Error:(2, 15) TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
```

Please check and tell me why? Is it a bug of typescript compiler or WebStorm? Which issue platform should I go? Thanks.

Comment: When use webstorm bounded typescript 1.4 compiler, everything is OK.

Comment: Can you add the parameters that you are passing to the two versions of the compiler?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is fixed for master: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2998